# Is Pinch Zoom(zooming like we do on image) available in Firefox Developer Edition for macOS? If yes, how to enable it?

Tags: macos, firefox, pinchzoom, firefox-developer-edition

I have tried the solution given on this link
https://itstillworks.com/enable-zoom-pinch-firefox-macbook-21731.html

This seems to just increase the zoom percentage as can be done by <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>. But what I wanted was the way Chrome and Safari do it, to zoom into a particular part of the page(the part where the pointer is) and then you can scroll also in those particular settings. Like zooming in as if the webpage was an image. 
Is this feature available in Firefox?

Comment: Same question as https://superuser.com/questions/1151173/pinch-to-zoom-in-firefox on Super User

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open a new tab in Firefox and type in `about:config` to go to its configuration window. This will probably take you to a window that warns you about the risks of incorrectly modifying settings. Simply click "I accept the risk!" to continue. Then search for the setting called `apz.allow_zooming` and set it equal to true.

Answer (score 1):

Pinch zooming is used by default starting in Firefox 83, released on November 17, 2020, both on Windows and Mac. ([release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/83.0/releasenotes/)) As before, whether pinch zooming is enabled is controlled by the `apz.allow_zooming` setting in `about:config`, so you can disable it if you like.